# Javascript gem "format.js"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to upload file with javascript AJAX but I have an error InvalidAuthenticutyToken when I correct my code like I see on many website another error appear : `Unknown format` in :

```
if @personal.save
    format.js
end
```

In my IDE the `.js` do an error : cannot find `js`

I think I miss a gem. My installed gems in order to use javascript are :

```
gem 'coffee-rails',          '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'coffee-script-source',  '1.8.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder',              '~> 2.0'
```

And my form is

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @personal, :html => {:multipart => true}, :remote => true do |f| %>
<div class="modal-body">
  <%= f.text_field :trigramme, label: "Trigramme" %>
  <%= f.text_field :nom, label: "Nom" %>
  <%= f.text_field :prenom, label: "Prenom" %>
  <%= f.text_field :poste, label: "Poste" %>
  <%= f.text_field :arrivee, label: "Arrivee a OCTO" %>
  <%= f.text_area :bio, label: "Bio", :rows => "5" %>
  <%= f.file_field :img, label: "Photo" %>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <%= link_to "Cancel", "#", class: "btn", data: {dismiss: "modal"} %>
</div>
```

It's weird because when I have the error of Invalid AuthenticutyToken my image is correctly uploaded in database but I have the error.
I have some `js.erb` file that print a popup with the form. I have tried remotipart but nothin happen I have again the error.

Do I miss a gem in order to use javascript due to second error `unknownFormat`? What is my problem ? Do you have a clue?

Comment: What is your IDE? Do you have the same error when you perform upload, or just and IDE warning?

Comment: My IDE is Rubymine. I have the error Unknown format in my browser when I start the server.

Comment: I just see in my server logs : ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/defaults.js"):

Comment: Let's clarify things. Do you still get `Unknown format` error? What is exactly the text of `unknown format` error?

Comment: There is no more problem I don't understand. I spent like 10 hour on the problem and now that work see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the save is successful you want to respond with the correct format.

`if @personal.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js # actually means: if the client ask for js -> return file.js
  end
else
  #handle unsuccessful save
end`

Check out the api docs on [respond_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to)

Comment: I just see in my server logs : `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/defaults.js"):`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.
After try all your solution (none works).

I simply put :

`rails generate jquery:install`

That put me an error and install nothing but now it work.

I try to remove and put again your solution with the "else" and restart your server each time but that affect nothing. I don't know what is really the problem and the solution but I spent several hours on it and now it work it's mystical.